# Android Connecting Multiple Devices via WiFi Socets

Tags: android, sockets

I am looking to create a simple app that will help me better understand sockets and how they work inside of Android. My idea is to try and create a simple messaging app that will allow users to connect to the host phone and then send messages.

I am hoping that once a message is sent all phones connected to the host will be able to see the messages and reply.

My question is that as I am very new to Android, is there any material out there or tutorials that will guide me into getting this up and running or something similar? Has anyone else tried something like this before and are sockets the best approach to be using?

Comment: One would not call that a simple app.

Comment: Should this work where? In one room only?

Comment: Just in a room or on the local WiFi yes

Comment: There is even a chat example that comes with the android sdk. And further there are so many client server examples found on this site. #### have done this before you. Its a nice project. You will learn a lot.

Comment: i don't want to have to create a server though, i was hoping that the host phone would be the server

Comment: Android phones are no chat servers. If you want to chat then you need a server app on one phone and  client apps on every other phone.

Comment: Even if it was just as a temporary situation? where by the data didn't need to be saved just displayed and then cleared once the app/session is closed?